# data hiding for a specified page in active reports

Tags: c#

As am new to active reports i don't know how to hide the details for a specific page,for example I am trying to show page total and grand total,I want to show the grand total  and page total in second page and page total in both pages,when am trying in active reports the grand total is showing in both pages

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put your grand total in a the report footer. That way it only appears at the end regardless of the number of pages.